# Rogue RA what is this and how to counter it?

Tags: ipv6, rogue

This content comes from one of my lectures on "security" module related to IP V6 section.

There is no reference in the suggested book or lecture slides what that exactly is. However it is constantly added up to content like:

"Apply appropriate IPv6 controls, even if "IPv4" only" (eg. rogue RA protection)

"IPv6 security issues:

- IpV4 equivalents
- new issues (IPv6 rogue RA) "

I tried to google - the content is not for mortal students. Could you please explain this phenomena of "rogue router advertisement".

I really need little detail, just what RA is, what exactly it does and why rogue RA is bad.

Thank you very much,

Comment: Very generic question there is plenty of documents out there explaining this, read RFC6104. Do you understand ARP spoofing/poisoning? RA tells LAN hosts 'hey LAN has subnet X and its router is Y', rogue RA has X and/or Y which are unexpected, potentially malicious information meant to draw traffic to attacker.

Comment: @ytti thanks, perfectly clear, I was confused since I expected more of rogue advertisement. It is not exactly the attack or harm but rather a setup for future attacks. Immediate effect asfaiu is that it any devices doing Rogue Advertisements(even unintentionally) can cause connection problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Router Advertisements (RAs) can provide autoconfiguration of default gateways for hosts instead of manually configuring each system.  The downside is similar to the Rogue DHCP Server scenario: A Rogue RA coming from a misconfigured router or even a Windows desktop in a wireless network, for example, can offer a default gateway that doesn't work as intended.

Appropriate controls could be ACLs to block these from untrusted interfaces or implement RA Snooping (aka RA Guard) similar to DHCP Snooping.

*See source of Rogue RA info @ RFC6104 [Rogue IPv6 Router Advertisement Problem Statement](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6104#section-3)*

*RA Guard config @ [Cisco IPv6 Configuration Guide](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/ipv6/configuration/15-2s/ip6-ra-guard.html)*